# When does a theory decouple?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, terminology, definition, interactions

The question is very broad, but it seems to me that the term 'to decouple' is also used in various contexts. For example, neutrinos decouple from the photons in the early Universe, when the interaction rate drops below the typical time of the thermal bath to change its temperature. But what does it mean when a theory decouples, e.g. in a statement like 'a theory decouples from gravity far below the Planck scale'.

What does it mean for the theory to decouple from gravity? Can this be seen in the Lagrangian?